# Git Ansible Clone issue

Tags: git, ansible

I've a git repo and following is my ansible git code.

```
---
 - name: read-write git checkout from repo
   git:
    repo: "{{repo_url}}"
    dest: "{{webapps_dir}}/{{app_name}}"
    accept_hostkey: yes
    force: yes
    remote: "{{repo_remote}}"
    version: "{{repo_branch}}"
   register: gitrepo
```

When I run the above task, it hangs-up/waits endlessly. I tried debugging and found out that when I add git host to the known hosts (manually going onto the server and then ading) , and then run this playbook, it works fine.

Although I've set `accept_hostkey` to `yes`, it still hangs up or waits endlessly.

How can I clone a git repo using the above playbook?

Comment: Did you try turning on the verbose mode ?

Comment: I tried. It still hangs or waits endlessly.

Comment: whats the O/P of that ?

Comment: Nothing..It just angs up ...

Comment: Any firewalls on your machine or in the network? Problems using ssl?

Comment: Had there been any firewall, it wouldnt have worked after adding `known_host` manually!!!

Comment: Which Ansible Version are you using? There had been some issues concerning `accept_hostkey: yes`.

Comment: Yup, I've had issues with accept_hostkey: yes as well, and found the only workaround to be to manually add the hostkey before running git.

Answer (score 0):

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "gituser"
      prompt: "Enter your gitlab ID or username ex: user@XXXX.XXX"
      private: no
    - name: "gitpassword"
      prompt: "Enter your gitlab password"
      private: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Cloning from git 
      git:
        repo: "https://{{ gituser | urlencode }}:{{ gitpassword | urlencode }}@git###.####.###/group/projects.git"
        dest: /usr/share/clonefolder
        clone: yes
        update: yes
        force: yes
```

This may help you. Accept_hostkey im working on it. i will update you once i complete it.

Thanks